# Unity: CountDownTimer to stop when it reaches 00:00:00

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, timer, countdown

so i have this code which is basically a count down timer, my problem is that i want it to stop when it reaches 00:00:00.

currently when the code reaches 00:00:00, the seconds starts to count again from 00:00:59, so i hope if there is any one who can help me.

```
public class CountDownTimer : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public Text timerText;
     public float secondsCount;
     public int minuteCount;
     public int hourCount;
     void Update()
     {
         UpdateTimerUI();
     }
     //call this on update
     public void UpdateTimerUI()
     {
         //set timer UI
         if(secondsCount > 0)
         secondsCount -= Time.deltaTime;
         timerText.text = hourCount + "h:" + minuteCount + "m:" + (int)secondsCount + "s";
         if (secondsCount <= 0)
         {
             if(minuteCount > 0)
             minuteCount--;

             //if(minuteCount!= 0)
             secondsCount = 60;

         }

         else if (minuteCount <= 0)
         {
             if(hourCount > 0)
             hourCount--;

             if(hourCount != 0)
             minuteCount = 60;
         }

          if (secondsCount <= 0 && minuteCount <= 0 && hourCount <= 0)
         {
             Debug.Log("gameOver");
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the part that is resetting your timer.

```
 if (secondsCount <= 0)
     {
         if(minuteCount > 0)
         minuteCount--;

         //if(minuteCount!= 0)
         secondsCount = 60;

     }
```

If you want your timer to clamp at 0 just say

```
if(secondsCount <=){
    secondsCount = 0;
}
```

If you dont want it to start over you can just remove the line

```
secondsCount = 60;
```

or you could add a bool that records the state of your clock.

```
bool timeIsOver = false;
```

and then trigger it when the seconds are up.

```
if(timeIsOver == false){
secondsCount -= Time.deltaTime;
}
if(secondsCount <= 0  ){
   timeIsOver = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote it using coroutines and `TimeSpan` (pseudo code):

```
private IEnumerator Countdown(int totalSeconds)
{
   while (totalSeconds > 0)
   {
     var time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(totalSeconds);
     timerText.text = $"{time.Hours}:{time.Minutes}:{time.Seconds}";
     yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
     totalSeconds--;
   }

   Debug.Log("Game over");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i found another answer, and thought that it may helpful for anyone who's passing by

```
public Text timerText;
 [SerializeField, Range(0, 59)] private int seconds;
 [SerializeField, Range(0, 59)] private int minutes;
 [SerializeField, Range(0, 23)] private int hours;
 private float timer;
 private void Start()
 {
     timer = hours * 3600f + minutes * 60 + seconds;
 }
 void Update()
 {
     UpdateTimerUI();
 }
 //call this on update
 public void UpdateTimerUI()
 {
     timer = Mathf.Max(timer - Time.deltaTime, 0);
     hours = Mathf.FloorToInt(timer / 3600);
     minutes = Mathf.FloorToInt((timer - hours * 3600) / 60);
     seconds = Mathf.FloorToInt(timer - hours * 3600 - minutes * 60);
     timerText.text = string.Format("{0:00}h:{1:00}m:{2:00}s", hours, minutes, seconds);
     if (timer <= Mathf.Epsilon)
     {
         Debug.Log("gameOver");
         enabled = false;
     }
 }
```